# Why CONTAINS method doesn't work with REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I'm trying to execute a query with `REPLACE` method within a `CONTAINS` method like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, REPLACE('abcd', 'a', 'b'))
```

But the query returns an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Is "abcd" a column or a static value?

Comment: The double quote character is NOT a string delimiter - that's the first problem. But your query makes little logical sense so it is likely your example is very different from your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as below:

```
declare @param nvarchar(100)='abcd';

    set @param=  REPLACE(@param,'a','b');

    SELECT *
    FROM PersonAddress
    WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, @param)
```

But first, You need to do this

[image: full-text search index]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `cte`

```
with cte as
(
  select 
    *
  from A
  where REPLACE('abcd', 'a', 'b') as col
)

select 
  *
from cte
where contains(col, name)
```